# Django backend receives one less param than sent by frontend

Tags: django, angularjs, rest

I have a small web app with AngularJS front-end and Django ReST in the back.  There's a strange hitch going on when I make `POST` request to the web service: the browser console clearly shows 3 parameters being sent, but the backend logging reports only 2 params received.  The result is that the server throws a code 500 error due to a bad database lookup.

Here's the code:

## Client

```
        var b = newQuesForm.username.value;
        $http.post('/myapp/questions/new', {username:b,title:q.title,description:q.description}).
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              $http.get('/myapp/questions').success(function(data){
                    $scope.questions = data;
                    q = null;
                    $scope.newQuesForm.$setPristine();
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(headers+data);
                  });
          }).
          error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(headers+data);
          });
```

Both my manual logging and the dev console show a string like:

```
{"username":"admin","description":"What's your name?","title":"question 1"}
```

## Server

```
class CreateQuestionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    author = UserSerializer(required=False)
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = serializers.CharField(max_length=350)

    def create(self, data):
        q= Question()
        d = data
        q.title = d.get('title')
        q.description = d.get("description")
        q.author = User.objects.get(username=d.get('username'))
        q.save()
        return q
```

Server-side logging shows the `username` parameter never succeeds in making the trip, and thus I end up with code 500 and error message:

`User matching query does not exist.` (No user with id=none)

What's causing some of the data to get lost?

Comment: I think the `username` is not field in your `serializer` and so you are not getting it in data in `create` function. Check around this and you'll get something.

Comment: I think you may be right, be I'm not sure to declare it as a field, since it's nested.  `username` is a field of the `User` model, obviously, not `Question`.  I tried declaring 
`class Meta: 
    model=Question
    fields=("title","description","username")`
But that didn't work, neither did `fields=("title","description","author")`
Do you know what the prepare way to declare a nested field is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the problem was really with the serialization of fields, as @nikhiln began to point out.  I followed his lead to refactor the code, moving the `create()` method to api.py, rather than serializers.py, and stopped relying altogether on the client-side data for the user's identity, something that was a bit silly in the first place (passing `User` to a hidden `input` in the view, and then harvesting the username from there and passing it back to the server in the AJAX params).  Here's the new code, that works perfectly:

```
class QuestionCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    model = Question
    serializer_class = CreateQuestionSerializer

    def create(self, request,*args,**kwargs):
        q= Question()
        d = request.data
        q.title = d.get('title')
        q.description = d.get("description")
        q.author = request.user
        q.save()
        if q.pk:
            return Response({'id':q.pk,'author':q.author.username}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response({'error':'record not created'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So here, I do it the right way: pull the `User` from the `request` param directly in the backend.